# Facebook php sdk not working but javascript is

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

The subdomain i am hosting is http://gaat.yzi.me

I am using the example in facebook php sdk to retrieve a user profile.

However after i give my credentials and permissions the url changes to

```
http://gaat.yzi.me/?code=AQAYcdk1WIpTBc0YBg5xDLZzYeaCjjCssWUGAKxfFBTuu61HSFswBw5ni5LEFuGH38XjQI-oYYVw0kxQH5QUfg3-WAbE0vVa9vqGI-xGJ93YHfbHndo6JG8Q7zmup2f-6M4cc9rG2yh7KP4WZdAYLaDORnDGF3cfGUEs8_vYUiie0XeLC9mhL9V7OxPtiy41eUPfvSJrD4fPZnrWnoA50zWJxE0tuXpWAuW0NAXwj0hVE8fvpjNVM5brfsSn78WzPiQndTiMzo46VHhZ4Frncg5phG0CMsY6bDv5OXteIHptdpR2kdywXvXcY6JmCVzStU0&state=6069ceac64cee10e09bd3ae33c9f3680#_=_
```

But `$user_id` remains `0`.
I have tried multiple solutions but none work. Is it because of a certain cpanel setting(using php 5.3) or `.htaccess` file?
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.. Didnt have php-curl installed.. Sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 0):

You have to exchange the code for an Access Token, as described in the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id={app-id}    
    &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &code={code-parameter}
```